# using JQuery to show image from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JQuery, this seems like something really simple, but I am having problems getting an image to show when the image URL is entered into an input text box. All I get is the text of the image, ex. "http://dreamatico.com/data_images/car/car-6.jpg" instead of the pic itself.

Comment: Please show code being used. Sounds like you aren't using `<img>` tag, but without more details question is not clear

Comment: Do you insert image address into <img> tag?

Comment: It looks like that site has some configuration to disable hotlinking, so images are redirected to the homepage unless the referrer is the site itself.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little bit unsure of what your problem really was, but I suspect it was like Alec Ananian mentioned in the comments above if you were testing with the image you linked (the site of the image not allowing different referer than current host).

I made you a short fiddle that eats the input text and puts it into the src of an img tag using all jQuery and .attr().

For future questions though, you should describe your problem a little bit more. Preferably with your current code (in a fiddle or showing it as a snippet directly here). Basically make it as easy as possible for people to help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/tv0evg7d/1/

Html:

```
<input id="inputBox" value="http://www.clusterflock.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/owl-in-a-hat.jpg"/>
<button id="loadImage">Show</button>
<br/>
<img id="image" src="" alt="No image loaded"/>
```

JS:

```
$("#loadImage").on('click', function(){
    $("#image").attr("src", $("#inputBox").val());
});
```